# Viewing an image on a Android Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, nullpointerexception

I am having trouble showing an image from the drawable folder on to a fragment.
When I try to show do it, it comes up with a `java.lang.NullPointerException`. 
any help would be appreciated.

This is my code,

```
public class Fragment4 extends Fragment {
    public Fragment4() {
    }

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate (R.layout.fragment4, container, false);
        ImageView image = (ImageView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.image);
        image.setImageResource(R.drawable.image123);
        return  rootView;
    } 
}
```

XML file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<ImageView
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: can you add the layout xml file also

Comment: What is the referred line number of the NullPointerException? (and what line does that number refer to)

Comment: the NullPointerException refers to this line of code "image.setImageResource(R.drawable.image123);"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `ImageView` has no `id`. Set it as follows,

```
<ImageView
   android:id="@+id/image"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Answer (score 3):

It is because you didn't add id attribute to the image in xml
Try this:

```
<ImageView
android:id="@+id/image"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```